# Refresh Portable Object Localization in ASP.NET Core MVC during Run Time

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with using PortableObject files to manage localization of my ASP.NET Core MVC web application.

The file is a .PO file.

I have been asked if its possible to refresh these files (update them) and not have to restart the app pool or anything for the web application to pick the changes?

From all of the research I have done, I can't seem to find an answer. If someone could please point me in the direction of "yes" or "no" and if "yes", how, I would appreciate it!

I am also using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.

Comment: Which kind of files you want to change, could you explain more detail about them? If these files will be compiled to the .dll files, I suppose you have to publish it again. 
Besides, you could also try refreshing these files without restart the app pool, if the web app will load the latest values, it means there is no need to restart the app pool, else, you have to restart it.

Comment: The type of file is a .po file. I will also add this to the question.